# How to verify Dynamic drop down values in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Currently working on **Selenium WebDriver** and using **Java** for scripting.

I have stored all drop down values of db in property file and want to compare same values whether they are in UI as in DropDown options.

For example, i have a drop down called Project,Product and it contains many options in the drop down 400+ projects. And if any new Projects is included it will added in the drop down as well.

In this case how can i verify the options is matching in UI.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you can figure out how to retrieve the reference values from within the property file into your Java code. Some pointers, if your property file is in `key=value` format: [`Property.load`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.InputStream%29) and [`Property.getProperty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29).

Once you have loaded your properties:

- Look at the source of the page. (Use something like the "inspect element" option in Chrome) Typically the drop-down values will be `<li>`s under a `<ul>`.
- Use the [X-Path Helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl?hl=en) Plugin in Chrome to get the [Xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/) for the li elements.
- Let's say the Xpath is `//*[@id='some-id']/some-paths/ul/li`
- Get the subelements list as `List<WebElement> x = driver.findElements(By.xpath(//*[@id='some-id']/some-paths/ul/li));`
- Now loop through the list using `for (WebElement x1 : x) { //do something with x1 }`.
- Use something like `x1.getText()` or `x1.GetInnerHTML()` (depends on your page source) to get the text for the dropdown menu.
- Do basic String matching against your reference values.

This is just a basic guideline. You can modify and optimize this to no end.

Comment: Could you provide some sample code for the scenario

Comment: I believe that given the contents of the above reply, you can figure out the rest yourself. What have you tried so far, and where are you stuck?

Comment: I see that you have posted [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22802881/how-can-i-select-particular-drop-down-option-from-the-property-file-in-selenium) which is similar to this one. If you think my answer above was sufficient, please mark it as an answer so that this question can be closed.

Comment: Both are different questions. In this question i asked about the verification of the drop down list. In that question i have asked about selecting one option.